# Not receiving bounced emails from PHPList

Tags: email

I am sending a test campaign to my own address and to a fictitious nonsense address and I am receiving the email at my account but I am not receiving any bounces. My settings in the config.php file are:

```
$message_envelope = 'bounces@mydomain.com';

$bounce_protocol = 'pop';
$bounce_mailbox_host = 'localhost';
$bounce_mailbox_user = 'bounces@mydomain.com';
$bounce_mailbox_password = 'XXXXXX';
```

What's the next step in figuring out the problem? I also tried both variations of the following:

```
$bounce_mailbox_port = "110/pop3/notls";
#$bounce_mailbox_port = "110/pop3";
```

I am running a Godaddy Centos 6 VPS and Plesk 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After querying my ISP I have learned that the reason I was not receiving bounces is that I have exceeded my quota of smtp relays. After waiting for a day or so and clearing my message queue on the server I am now receiving my bounces.